# In Unity3D ,How do you play video on a game object a rectangle, for example, so that it acts like a television?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am new to Unity3D and need to know how do we play video on a game object a rectangle, for example so that it acts like a television.

Comment: Do not repeat your post! You have post it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22292577/how-to-play-news-in-tv-when-i-switch-on-using-scripting-language-in-unity3d

Answer (score 0):

A standard library version of this is available for Pro/Advanced users: https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/VideoFiles.html